# How to Conditionally render a Link Column with Django Tables 2?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

With the following table when returning the `BoundColumn` it is plaintext and not html.

```
class CarHistoryTable(tables.Table):

    edit = tables.LinkColumn(
        'Car:update',
        kwargs={'pk': A('id')},
        orderable=False,
        text='Edit'
    )

    def render_edit(self, record, value, bound_column):
        if record.state != Car.NEW:
            return ''
        return super().render_edit()
```

Ideally I want to return an empty text for Cars that are not `NEW` state. For other cars I would like to render the edit link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you assume you can call `super().render_edit()`, but that's 
not the case. The logic django-tables2 uses to decide what render-callable it should use looks like this:

> If a method `render_<columnname>` is defined on the table, it is used. In any other case, the `render()` method of the `tables.LinkColumn()` instance you assigned to `edit` while defining your `CarHistoryTable` is used.

Now, to achieve your goal, I'd do something like this:

```
class CarUpdateLinkColumn(tables.LinkColumn):
    def render(self, value, record, bound_column):
        if record.state != Car.NEW:
            return ''
        return super().render(value, record, bound_column)


class CarHistoryTable(tables.Table):
    edit = tables.CarUpdateLinkColumn(
        'Car:update',
        kwargs={'pk': A('id')},
        orderable=False,
        text='Edit'
    )
```

This defines a custom column derived from the LinkColumn you want in case of existing cars. The implementation of `render()` can call `super().render()` because such a method actually exists.

Comment: I am getting an error `render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'column' from this line: `return super().render(record=record, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Ah the signature should be `return super().render(value, record, bound_column)`

Comment: do you use the same method signature as in the above example?

Comment: Yes. Check the signature here: https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/columns/linkcolumn.py#L180

Comment: Yes, but I was under the impression that `*args, **kwargs` would do the magic. Anyway, it works for you now!